# Schedule crontab job with input parameters to script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to schedule a certain bash script with crontab. The script takes two input arguments. When I execute the file through the shell manually, it runs fine and I can see the process running afterwards. Scheduling the job via crontab, however, does not work. I redirect the output to a log file and that file does get created when the time of scheduling comes but it is empty. The process on the other hand is not started.

This is my crontab line:

```
20 10 * * * /home/user/path/scripts/startprocess.sh 8003 prod >> /home/user/logs/crontabtest.log 2>&1
```

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PORT=$1
export STAGE=$2
nohup q /home/user/repo/load.q -p $PORT > /home/user/logs/q_${PORT}.log 2>&1 &
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `nohup -q` and `&`, those are to run the process in the background, contrab already run in the background.

Comment: I have removed nohup and & at the end. Now, I am getting ```q command not found``` but in the shell i can use this command without any problems

Comment: q is not a standard command in bash. If q is a tool or a script try to add the full path to q, something like /usr/local/bin/q. To get the full path of q run `whereis q`.

Comment: @SanMu cron jobs run with a very minimal environment, including a default `PATH` of just `/usr/bin:/bin`, so it won't find commands outside of those two directories (unless you specify the full path). If your program/script/whatever has any other environmental dependencies, those may also be missing and you'll have to either add them to the crontab or to the wrapper script.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script has executable permisions, by default the root user is used also, if you want to use a different user then specify the user in your cronjob command.

You do not need `nohup` when using crontab.

Environment variables may not be available in crontab, so add your environment variables you require in your script.